# Dealing with different types of parameters during Unmarshal

Tags: json, list, go, struct

I'm working with some APIs from my Fritz!Box router, I'd like to unmarshal the json response in a decent struct, just need to find a good way to do that.

Sometimes in the API response the WLan parameter is a bool, other times is an object of this type

```
// WLan contains info about the Wireless Lan
type WLan struct {
    Txt     string `json:"txt"`
    Led     string `json:"led"`
    Title   string `json:"title"`
    Link    string `json:"link"`
    Tooltip string `json:"tooltip"`
}
```

If you need more info about the code you can use the [github repo](https://github.com/LucaTheHacker/GoFritzBox/).

I need to add the boolean wlan parameter, I've tried to duplicate the "Data" struct and change the name, but that solution sounds very bad to me.

Wlan is contained in this struct:

```
// Data contains data about the Fritz!Box
type Data struct {
    NasLink          string    `json:"naslink"`
    FritzOS          FritzOS   `json:"fritzos"`
    Webdav           int       `json:"webdav,string"`
    Manual           string    `json:"MANUAL_URL"`
    Language         string    `json:"language"`
    AVM              string    `json:"AVM_URL"`
    USBConnect       string    `json:"usbconnect"`
    Foncalls         Foncalls  `json:"foncalls"`
    VPN              VPN       `json:"vpn"`
    Internet         Internet  `json:"internet"`
    DSL              DSL       `json:"dsl"`
    ServicePortalURL string    `json:"SERVICEPORTAL_URL"`
    Comfort          Comfort   `json:"comfort"`
    Changelog        Changelog `json:"changelog"`
    TamCalls         TamCalls  `json:"tamcalls"`
    Lan              External  `json:"lan"`
    USB              External  `json:"usb"`
    FonNum           External  `json:"fonnum"`
    NewsURL          string    `json:"NEWSLETTER_URL"`
    Net              Net       `json:"net"`
    Dect             External  `json:"dect"`
    WLan             WLan      `json:"wlan"`
  //Wlan             bool      `json:"wlan"` # This is the other "case"
}
```

Comment: Is this used in another struct? If so, include the enclosing struct as well. There are multiple ways this can be solved, but you need to clarify what you want once the unmarshaling is done.

Comment: Yes, WLan is containted in data. Data unmarshals the "wlan" name to WLan, but sometimes instead of the json object there's a bool value. Anyway you can see the full source code on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a good solution, I'm still new to go, but anyway, you could use [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) and "delay" the unmarshal of `wlan` property into one of two separate struct fields. for example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// Data contains data about the Fritz!Box. (other fields omitted for brevity)
type Data struct {
    Language string           `json:"language"`
    NewsURL  string           `json:"NEWSLETTER_URL"`
    WLanRaw  *json.RawMessage `json:"wlan"`
    WLanBool bool             `json:"-"`
    WLanInfo *WLanInfo        `json:"-"`
}

// WLanInfo contains infos about the Wireless Lan
type WLanInfo struct {
    Txt     string `json:"txt"`
    Led     string `json:"led"`
    Title   string `json:"title"`
    Link    string `json:"link"`
    Tooltip string `json:"tooltip"`
}

func UnmarshalData(raw []byte, data *Data) error {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(raw, data); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    switch string(*data.WLanRaw) {
    case "true", "false":
        json.Unmarshal(*data.WLanRaw, &data.WLanBool)
    default:
        if err := json.Unmarshal(*data.WLanRaw, &data.WLanInfo); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    jsonBool := []byte(`
{
    "language": "it",
    "NEWSLETTER_URL": "https://example.com/news",
    "wlan": true
}`)

    jsonInfo := []byte(`
{
    "language": "it",
    "NEWSLETTER_URL": "https://example.com/news",
    "wlan": {
        "txt": "footxt",
        "led": "fooled",
        "title": "hello",
        "link": "bar",
        "tooltip": "baz"
    }
}`)

    // error handling omitted
    var dataBool Data
    UnmarshalData(jsonBool, &dataBool)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n\n", dataBool)

    var dataInfo Data
    UnmarshalData(jsonInfo, &dataInfo)
    fmt.Printf("%+v %+v\n", dataInfo, dataInfo.WLanInfo)
}
```

---

```
$ go build fritz.go
$ ./fritz
{Language:it NewsURL:https://example.com/news WLanRaw:0xc0000a4060 WLanBool:true WLanInfo:<nil>}

{Language:it NewsURL:https://example.com/news WLanRaw:0xc0000a4080 WLanBool:false WLanInfo:0xc0000b0000} &{Txt:footxt Led:fooled Title:hello Link:bar Tooltip:baz}
$
```

Comment: Can be a solution, but will cause issues when someone is checking for the "bool" property, since it will always be false

Comment: @LucaDametto it's "always `false`" when `wlan` property is an object in the json. well, `WLanBool` should be checked only if `WLanInfo` == `nil`. kinda ugly, I know...

Comment: Mhhh, can be a solution. I'll try to implement your example.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) and [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) interfaces.

```golang
type WLan struct {
    Bool    *bool  `json:"-"`
    Txt     string `json:"txt"`
    Led     string `json:"led"`
    Title   string `json:"title"`
    Link    string `json:"link"`
    Tooltip string `json:"tooltip"`
}

// implements json.Unmarshaler
func (w *WLan) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if len(data) > 0 && (data[0] == 't' || data[0] == 'f') { // seems to be a bool
        w.Bool = new(bool)
        return json.Unmarshal(data, w.Bool)
    }
    if len(data) > 1 && data[0] == '{' && data[len(data)-1] == '}' { // it's an object
        // type W and the conversion (*W)(w) are required to
        // prevent encoding/json from invoking the UnmarshalJSON
        // method recursively causing a stack overflow
        type W WLan
        return json.Unmarshal(data, (*W)(w))
    }
    return nil // or error, up to you
}

// implements json.Marshaler
func (w WLan) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if w.Bool != nil {
        return json.Marshal(*w.Bool)
    }
    // Same as with UnmarshalJSON, type W and the conversion W(w) are 
    // required to prevent encoding/json from invoking the MarshalJSON
    // method recursively causing a stack overflow
    type W WLan
    return json.Marshal(W(w))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/s72zt4ny7Pv